# Reel to reel tape speed is a little too slow

Tags: recorder, sony, tape, speed, reel

I have recently got a nice Sony TC-645 Reel to reel taperecorder. It seems to be in a generally good condition. Everything works. But: the tape speed is a little bit too slow. When I play music at 7,5inch speed the music is about 'one tone' lower than it should be.
I have found out, that if I press really hard down onto the capstan (the metal pin that gets the whole thing going) with i.e. a screwdriver, the speed increases to the normal and has the correct speed.
My question is, how can I make the capstan have a permanent sufficient pressure (without my help)?

Hope someone has some nice knowledge about this so I can fix it! :)

Best wishes,
Joakim

Comment: Hi Jox, your question about the mechanics of your recorder are probably off-topic in this SE, but what's probably happening is that rubber weels in the transmission system have become hard and lost traction. You'd probably need to identify which parts are giving the problem and find spares in the market (there are rubber spares manufacturers for old audio equipments out there).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Yes, it's a bit off topic but I saw a few other questions on reel to reel and thought give it a chance here ;) I'll search for a spare manufacturer.